# Problema con if, no determina correctamente != en lenguaje c

Tags: condiciones, fibonacci

buenas noches.

Cabe recalcar que sigo siendo un novato en esto de la programación :/

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo que crear un programa que imprima el Fibonacci invertido,
es decir, los números que no pertenecen al Fibonacci tienen que imprimirse.
Un ejemplo sería 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34. En este caso tengo que imprimir 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14 y así.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int num,i,a,b,c,j;

printf("Ingresa el limite: ");
scanf("%i",&num);

a=1; b=1; c=0; i=0;
for (i=1; i<=num; i++){
    if(i!=a && i!=b && i!=c)
        printf("%i ",i);
    c=a+b;
    a=b;
    b=c;
}
}
```

Este es el código que tengo, el problema es que if filtra solo algunos números.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Ya intente de diferentes formas, y no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema que veo es que deberías actualizar las variables solo cuando `i == c`. Porque si lo haces a cada bucle, i aumentará de 1 en uno, pero c aumentará en la escala Fibonacci. Ej: i hará: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, pero c hará: 2, 3, 5, 8, 13. Y así i != c casi siempre.

Prueba con este bucle:

```c
a = 1;
b = 1;
c = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

    // Actualiza a, b, y c solo cuando i alcance el valor de c.
    if (c <= i) {
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }

    if (i != a && i != b && i != c) {
        printf("%i ", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Entiendo, te agradezco por tu tiempo en apoyarme, muchas gracias, funciona!